# Is there a way to format text into table rows? | PHP script

Tags: php, text, format, rows

Last question for today (hopefully).

So I'm running a pure .php script via cmd and I want to format the text output into "rows" or so that the outputs are in look-a-like rows.

Currently I'm using the *"\t"* formatting, but once a variable "skips" a tab (is too big for the row) the whole row is shifted a tab more than the previous / following row (maybe).

```
echo 'TestText: ', $variable . "\t" . '[' . $variable 2...
```

whereas the "$variable often changes in length by one or two tabs, making the "\t" or "\t\t" shifting to much.

**So my question:** Is there any way to properly format this kind of "table" with proper text rows?

Comment: I'd appreciate a reply instead of the thread being disliked. I've done my research and haven't found a proper solution besides the (as mentioned) non-functioning "\t" approach.

Comment: Hard to understand your exact meaning here - for instance `once a variable "skips" a tab`? What does that mean? When you mention `table` - what table? You are using the commandline to run the script to explain what the `table` is. Again `$variable often changes in length by one or two tabs` ? Which variable - where is this coming from?

Comment: Gotcha! By table I meant (as the echo is in a loop) that the different text lines displayed will be alined horizontally. Currently it looks like that: https://prnt.sc/prv3wu
Due to the fact that the names / variables / the text (hidden by the rectangle) can differ in length (as seen in the picture) the following text will shift too far / too less. The goal would be that each block / text has it's certain start point like being in a "invisible" table.

Comment: And yes, I'm running the whole thing on Windows via cmd by executing the PHP script with php filename.php

Comment: you could remove the `successfully added` and then, based upon expected max length of those elements hidden by red overlay use a padding function to add blank spaces to the end of that variable so they remain a constant width. But without code it is like asking "how long is a piece of string?" - impossible to answer!

Comment: The length differs, thus I wanted to "skip" three tabs ("\t") before writing the "[". But once a name gets longer, exactly skipping the next tab mark, it will add three tabs meaning that it's still not aligned. //EDIT: maximum length is 30 characters

Comment: But that part with the padding function sounds interesting. Adding only two "\t" if text is > 15 or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

Not a smooth solution, but it's one: Implemented a if/elseif/else and tried to count how many characters the variable is allowed to have before it would reach the next "tab point".
Took this point and decreased the amount of tabs needed accordingly to the increase of characters.